# OAuthPrompt/SigniIn for AzureAD always defaults to SSO credentials. How to request for alternate creds?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have made a bot for a customer.
the purpose is to run admin commands through a secured API.

For this, they need to be

1. Logged on the teams using their standard account
2. When they execute an admin command, bot asks for OAuth Login (Connection is set to AzureAD v2 mode).
3. In teams / tester in portal, it never asks for credentials, it just defaults to the logged on user.

How do I make it always just ask for credentials?

One way is to make a seperate AzureAD, but that then requires customer to pay for Premium AD once again, to be able to assign the AzureAD Roles defined for the admin API to groups and not single users.
So this is not a very good solution.

They can also add teams license to their admin account, but that breaks the whole workflow and reason to have a bot. cause they would have to have a browser open with admin creds logged to teams.

I hope this is possible, otherwise I am super sad, that some amazing admin scenario possibilities are lost. Unfortunately none of our enterprise customers, would allow to trigger various admin APIs using the employees standard account.

Comment: Why do you want to ask for credentials if they are already authenticated via teams?

Comment: What credentials do you want to use when the admin command is executed and more importantly why?

Comment: I want to ask, as their teams user is not their admin user. These are sysadmins, and for any admin tasks such as security "ISOLATE MACHINEX", they need to use their admin account rather than the personal teams account.
This is following any best practice guideline from MSFT when doing admin tasks.

When asking for login to azure AD, its super simple, you just add "&prompt=Select_Account" to the request.

But as the botframework logon site is handling it, I don't seem to find a way to set that flag.

It seems to be to be an easy add with lots of advantages for admins.

Comment: if we can't do it. No team bot can be made that does any admin functions if a company is following MSFT best practices & security guidelines

Comment: I want to use the credentials of their own admin account, that admin account has custom roles assigned in AzureAD. The Connection then uses user_impersonation to get those roles and then authenticates with a backend, that only allowed a certain admin to run certain commands. You might want to have one admin to be able to isolate a machine from network, but have less or more admins to be able to unisolate it again.

Comment: it works great, with the personal account. But that is super bad practice to do any kind of admin tasks as a sysadmin, using the same account as you use for email/communication.

Comment: if the 
https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=xxxx

could support adding a flag like prompt=select_account and we add that to the settings of the OAuthPrompt class, this could be easily obtained.

Otherwise I will have to make my own token store / call back ednpoint in the bot web app.

I just seems to me like such an easy win for you, that shouldnt require much work as I see it. (It might even already exist, but we dont know, as the https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=xxx is not documented anywhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this totally answers your question and I'm a bit confused by what you want. but from what I'm understanding, 
I followed this documentation here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample

the sample has a bot that authenticates with azure ad, it pops up the azure log in window every time for me in teams. a please sign in button appears, then you click sign in, and it pops up the login window which then you can get the token for and use that to call graph and etc.

I tested this out and when I talk to the bot, it always asks me to sign in, so hopefully this is what you're looking for? if not, please specify which part its missing, thanks

edit: the instructions are for the aad v1 endpoint, but if you want to use the v2 endpoint, it's nearly the same. just less to type, also you need to enter the scopes that you give api permissions to, eg "User.Read User.ReadBasic.All etc etc"

**Update**
So upon further discussion I saw what your issue was. what you need to do is the following. in the bot channels registration -> settings -> oauthconnectionsettings, take note of your values and delete it.

Then create a new one, under same name, 
with these parameters,

```
service provider: Oauth 2 Generic Provider
ClientID: same as before
secret: same as before. 
scope list delimiter: ' '
authorization URL Template: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize   (Replace Common with your tenant, just because i was using common)
Auth URL Query string template (this is key): ?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&scope={Scopes}&state={State}&prompt=login 
token url template: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token (again replace common with your tenant id)
token url query string tempalte : ?
token body template: code={Code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}
refresh url template: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token  (again replace common with your tenant id)
refresh url query string: ?
refresh body template: refresh_token={RefreshToken}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}
scopes: Mail.Read Mail.Send User.Read User.ReadBasic.All  (or whatever your scopes are)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer
 This is the sample I am using. But the popup automatically logs in on most computers if they have single sign on enabled.

Comment: This is why I want to be able to set the prompt parameter to make sure it always asks. So that anyone can login with their admin  account when they need to.

Comment: The behavior is different in tester and in the teams client. At least some times I was asked in the tester. Itnall depends on if the computer has an account already logged in (sso, azure ad joined etc). And then prompt=select_accont is not set. It will either ask or auto login. it is a super simple add-on to the functionality of token.botframework.com.

Comment: I don't understand why you guys are confused. It super simple. Always ask for logon even if sso is enabled. So that a user can use their high priveledge admin account to do admin actions via the bot. It's a super standard thing to use admin accounts for admin actions? Does that make sense ? :)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me if you expect it to always ask. It does not. I'll make an issue on GitHub to get some more eyes on this as it's a big showstopper and something very basic in azure ad logon. The thing is that in most cases , sso is great for personal stuff like calendar etc but without the option to set prompt=select_account  and force a selection of an account, it's unusable for any admin scenario. I could try to see if v1 has different behavior for some reason.

Comment: I see, interesting. out of curiosity, are you using the common endpoint or a specific tenant id in your setup?

Comment: Here is the prompt behavior explained for msal. But its a basic thing you just add to the auth . I always made s prototype for teams bot using a sign in card with a standard azure ad logon url including prompt=select_account and it always asks. But the I have to code the whole token manager system / callback api myself instead of using the oauthcard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-prompt-behavior

Comment: I am using a specific tenant. I tried common too though. Same behavior. Also common will not work as we need to force a single tenant

Comment: no worries, one more random test, did you try to type logout to the bot and then try to login again? does it prompt if you do that? or does it still SSO, ?

Comment: Always SSO. The only way I can get it to ask is if I somehow have more than one account logged in. Then it will ask which one otherwise SSO. I tried on 2 azure ad joined machines that have their account connected.

Comment: U think I should make a issue on GitHub ? Now that you helped discover that the behavior is different and I can write make a more precise description

Comment: Would be great if token.botframework.com was also open source so that I could just make a PR :)

Comment: actually. hang on a second. i just thought of a potential solution. let me test it.

Comment: YES! i think i got it. ok. i will edit my main post above

Comment: Ok I'll get my PC up so I can test !

Comment: It works! .. great thinking!. config is more verbose, but that makes no real difference (its setup by automation/arm template anyways)

Comment: I wish i could vote it up too (by 100s! lol), but I don't have the option to do that :D but you just saved my project with minimal work.

Comment: glad i could help! good luck with the rest of your project! :)

Comment: btw i chose to select prompt=select_account.. similar to login but lets them select if they already have multi logged in, or choose another account.. this is perfect!